# use c# how to read xml file

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

```
<Reports>
  <Databases>
    <Database>Axxest</Database>
    <Database>Axxest2</Database>
  </Databases>
</Reports>
```

how to read `Axxest`, `Axxest2` use c# to read xml file like this?

I try this:

```
XmlDocument xld = new XmlDocument();
xld.Load(XmlPath);
XmlNodeList xnl = xld.SelectSingleNode("Reports").ChildNodes;
tableList.Clear();
foreach (XmlNode xn in xnl)
{
    tableList.Add(xn.InnerText);
}
```

but something wrong?

Comment: XmlDocument xld = new XmlDocument();
                xld.Load(XmlPath);
                XmlNodeList xnl = xld.SelectSingleNode("BackupTables").ChildNodes;
                tableList.Clear();
                foreach (XmlNode xn in xnl)
                {
                    tableList.Add(xn.InnerText);
                }

Comment: Ok, please include what you have tried right away in future questions. And please also always specify exactly *what* went wrong, and in what line, and with what message. This will greatly improve your chances on getting suitable answers and good explanations :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try [`SelectNodes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z1a732z5%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method and `XPath`:

```
XmlDocument xld = new XmlDocument();
xld.Load(XmlPath);
XmlNodeList xnl = xld.SelectNodes("Reports/Databases/Database");
foreach (XmlNode xn in xnl)
{
    tableList.Add(xn.InnerText);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See the [Documentation's Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189056%28v=vs.95%29.aspx):

```
StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

String xmlString =
        @"<?xml version='1.0'?>
        <!-- This is a sample XML document -->
        <Items>
          <Item>test with a child element <more/> stuff</Item>
        </Items>";
// Create an XmlReader
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xmlString)))
{
    XmlWriterSettings ws = new XmlWriterSettings();
    ws.Indent = true;
    using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(output, ws))
    {

        // Parse the file and display each of the nodes.
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            switch (reader.NodeType)
            {
                case XmlNodeType.Element:
                    writer.WriteStartElement(reader.Name);
                    break;
                case XmlNodeType.Text:
                    writer.WriteString(reader.Value);
                    break;
                case XmlNodeType.XmlDeclaration:
                case XmlNodeType.ProcessingInstruction:
                    writer.WriteProcessingInstruction(reader.Name, reader.Value);
                    break;
                case XmlNodeType.Comment:
                    writer.WriteComment(reader.Value);
                    break;
                case XmlNodeType.EndElement:
                    writer.WriteFullEndElement();
                    break;
            }
        }

    }
}
OutputTextBlock.Text = output.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find some nodes in a xml file, you can use XPath for query, and here is all you  need in [w3 schools](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/default.asp).

If you debug the code, you can find the count of xnl is one, it only includes "Databases" node. "SelectSingleNode" means select one node, and in your code, "Reports" is first selected, then return its childnodes, which only contains "Databases". You can try Ria's code, use SelectNodes instead of SelectSingleNode. But you can still use "SelectSingleNode", try this:

```
XmlNodeList xnl = xld.SelectSingleNode("Reports/Databases").ChildNodes;
```

Hope it's helpful to you.